# Shell - Processing files in loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am working on a shell script and got stuck to a point where I need to pass arguments to a function. But it is not currently working as expected. I request you to kindly go through the script and let me know what I am missing here.

If I write below code in the script file (test.sh) directly without any function then it is working fine.

```
source ./logger.sh
now=$(date +"%Y.%m.%d_%H.%M.%S")
logFile="/path/to/the/directory/${now}.log"
touch $logFile
scriptName="test.sh"
source="/path/to/the/directory"
older=7

while IFS= read -r -d $'\0'; do
  printf "\nIn while: Currently processing file: ${REPLY}\n"
  file=$REPLY
  log 1 $scriptName "main" "Currently processing file: ${file}" $logFile
done < <(find ${source} -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +${older} ! -name '*.FLAG' ! -name '*.FAIL' -print0)
```

Output in the file

```
2021-Oct-24 09:37:12            test.sh:    main:   Currently processing file: /path/to/the/directory/file1.txt
2021-Oct-24 09:37:12            test.sh:    main:   Currently processing file: /path/to/the/directory/file2.txt
..... more files ...
```

However, when I encasulate the script into a function call then it does not work fine.

```
function moveFiles() {
  source=$1
  older=$2
  logFile=$3

  log 1 $scriptName "moveFiles" "Finding files from ${source} which changed before ${older} days." $logFile

  while IFS= read -r -d $'\0'; do
    printf "\nIn while: Currently processing file: ${REPLY}\n"
    file=$REPLY
    log 1 $scriptName "moveFiles" "Currently processing file: ${file}" $logFile
  done < <(find ${source} -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +${older} ! -name '*.FLAG' ! -name '*.FAIL' -print0)

  log 1 $scriptName "moveFiles" "For loop completed" $logFile

}

source ./logger.sh
now=$(date +"%Y.%m.%d_%H.%M.%S")
logFile="/path/to/the/directory/${now}.log"
touch $logFile
scriptName="test.sh"

moveFiles "/path/to/the/directory" 7 $logFile
log 2 $scriptName "main" "Move files - completed" $logFile
```

Output in the file

```
2021-Oct-24 09:43:23            test.sh:    moveFiles:  Finding files from /path/to/the/directory which changed before 7 days.
2021-Oct-24 09:43:23            test.sh:    moveFiles:  For loop completed
```

The output I am getting when I run the script directly without function, I need to have the same output via function as well. Please help me figuring out the issue.

Also I would like to prefer looping an array of files instead of providing find command output to while loop. I could not find any valid solution, that is why I opted using this approach. If there is any better approach, I would definitely like to opt that.

**Note:** The log function is in the logger.sh which I included via source ./logger.sh and it seems to be working fine.

**EDIT 1:** I am looking for a way to store the find command output to array and then send the array to another function and use loop there to process the elements of the array. Is there a better way that I can do? I tried below but it is not working. I always get only 1 element in the array.

```
list=$(find ${source} -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +${older} ! -name '*.FLAG' ! -name '*.FAIL' -print0)
processInLoop ${list[@]}
```

In the other function

```
function processInLoop(){
fileList=("${@}")

}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check your script with shellcheck, fix them, then come back. There are many multiple problems with your script, and it looks to me that all can be fixed with shellcheck.

Answer (score 0):

Tried below with your directory and filters in find statement .

```
function moveFiles() {
source=$1
older=$2
logFile=$3

echo 1 $scriptName "moveFiles" "Finding files from ${source} which changed before ${older} days." $logFile

find ${source} -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +1  -name '*' -print0 |
while IFS= read -r -d ''; do
  echo "\nIn while: Currently processing file: ${REPLY}\n"
  file=$REPLY
  echo $scriptName "moveFiles" "Currently processing file: ${file}" 
  $logFile
done

echo $scriptName "moveFiles" "For loop completed" $logFile

}

now=$(date +"%Y.%m.%d_%H.%M.%S")
logFile="."
touch $logFile
scriptName="test.sh"

moveFiles "." 7 $logFile
echo $scriptName "main" "Move files - completed" $logFile
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and unfortunately it is not working. I need to call a separate function for logging as I mentioned in the question-code so that i can apply formatting the output at one place.

Comment: I tested that locally and it's still working , please share the output you are getting and also you can replace echo with your log function as it's just a echo command with more options . I don't thing log function is a issue .

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for a way to store the find command output to array ...

For that use `readarray`.

```
readarray -d '' -t arr < <(find ....)
yourfunction "${arr[@]}"
```

---

There are many problems with the script - unquoted variable expansions, using normal variable as array, trying to store zero byte in a string. Check your script with shellcheck.

Quote Variable expansions to prevent word splitting and filename expansion. Don't `touch $logFile`, do `touch "$logFile"`.

`$'\0'` is the same as `''`. Every string ends with zero byte, two zero bytes is the same as one zero byte, as strings are interpreter up to the first zero byte.

Subjective: I am not a fan of pascal case, I prefer snake case.

`list=$(... -print0)` - because strngs store up to a zero byte, you can't store zero byte in a variable. You can pipe it via `xxd -p` to convert to hex, or read it to array as presented above. You *should* get a warning from bash about it.

`list=$(...) ; func ${list[@]}` - variable expansion is not quoted, so it undergoes word splitting and filename expansion. `list` is not an array, so it has only one element. `list=$( ... )` assigns a variable, `list=( ... )` would assign an array.

Subjective: `find ... ! ...` - while in history expansion is disabled in non-interactive scripts, I would advise to quote `!` anyway just so when you copy stuff to terminal to "test it out", histoty expansion wouldn't be triggered. I would do `find ... '!' ...`